# actionNext(or any ImeOption) doesn't work on my Edittext, also I can't select any other text field when this particular one is selected

Tags: android, imeoptions

This is such a confusing behavior to me, and I can't find anyone else with exactly my problem.

I am trying to create a login activity, and so far the username-field is giving me a lot of trouble. The textfield stays focused no matter what.

It doesn't lose focus if I click outside, I can't click any other field and I can't close the keyboard. Only back-button works in getting out.
I tried making it a one-line field by using every combination of `SingleLine`, `MaxLines` and `Lines`.... I also tried to use ImeOptions/ImeActionId `actionNext` which also had no effect.

It stubbornly keeps its enter-button that continues to create new lines despite setting `SingleLine` to true.

Right now my xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_huge">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mini_logo"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_huge">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/orange_ring"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/loginUsername"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeActionId="6"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="login!"
                android:onClick="userLogin"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: ehm sorry, I forgot to ask the question. 
Can someone tell me what's going on or if I misunderstood something or how to fix this? :) I really have no idea what I can do right now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Combining `android:maxLines="1"` with `android:inputType="text"` works for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Add this line android:singleLine="true" to your EditText.